# What is a good makeshift coin holder or organizer?

Tags: substitute-tool, organization

I have loose change that I empty out each day on my dresser. The change always seems to get in the way when I need to use the dresser to write on paper. I'd like to find a way to organize the change so it doesn't take up as much dresser space. I know I could purchase a piggy bank, but I don't want to spend any money on this. I've tried putting the change in a drawer, but then it gets all over and in my way when I put clothes in and back out of the drawer. I've also tried putting them in a plastic bag, but I really hate that option since it is really tacky, and I need to open and close the bag each time I have more coins to put in.

It doesn't matter if all the coins are mixed in some makeshift container together or if there's some makeshift contraption that organizes the denominations of the coins as well. Either one will work for me.

[image: Collection of small change]

Comment: What you're talking about isn't much of an organizer, it's more of a holder since all the coins are mixed up still. Consider changing the name to something more appropriate

Comment: I would recommend a clean yogurt carton or coffee can with slit in the lid :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use a hot chocolate tin with a slit in the lid:

[image]

*[Pot - Mad For Tools](http://www.mad4tools.com/cadbury-instant-hot-chocolate-2kg-tin-7158-p.asp)*, *[Knife - Barnitts and Stanley](http://www.barnitts.co.uk/products/details/2018.html), [Powder - WISEGeek](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-the-best-tips-for-a-brown-complexion.htm)*

Finished:

[image]

For me, the slit needs to be 30mm long and 4mm wide (to accommodate the £2 coin).

Comment: @Sompuperoo You'd wash it out first

Comment: @Sompuperoo Yeah, the tins can be washed as they have waterproofing and metal bases. I've edited the image so it has more details.

Comment: Yay, good illustrations :)

Comment: But not enough red freehand!

Comment: What a coincidence. I use the same Cadbury Hot Chocolate tin (mine being plastic) to store coins !

Answer (score 3):

Prescription bottles work well, especially because they keep larger coins such as quarters stacked.

For your usage, where you're looking for something to put various coins in, just use **a mug**.

Answer (score 2):

Use any bottle with the neck of size enough to push your coin in.

Kind of exotic bottle with coins:

> [image]
>
> [original image](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/glass-bottle-full-coins-25151412.jpg)

Usual plastic bottle:

> [image]
>
> [original image](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/plastic-bottle-coins-15281537.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A craft idea I have is to cut 4 or so old socks, probably right around the ankle part. Then take some string or rope, and cut some small holes in the socks for the string to pass through. Slide the string through the socks, then take another string and tie/adhere the ends together. With the other string, just adhere it to the wall with a nail or something. Thus I can have a nice organizational coin holders.

[image]

Another idea without worrying about organizing the denominations is I could just take an empty gallon water jug, cut it around the middle, and then just use the bottom part as a coin holder.

Comment: I feel like the socks would become too heavy and start ripping or cause damage to the wall it's nailed to. Have you tried this out before?

Comment: I would have thought this would be quite fiddly to get the coins out of the socks...?

Comment: @Tim not really, just grab the sock by the bottom, and tip it over. Works fine. Zach - obviously you could make this not strong enough, but as long as you use good enough string/rope  its not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind to keep the money together, any mug or bowl would do.
But if you want to separate out the coins, I would go for a series of smaller bowls or a divided plate.
When you take the money out, it takes a few seconds to put the money into the right part of the plate or the right bowl. When the little bowls get full, you can take one or its content, or several at the same time, to a shop and make the shop owner happy with sorted small change.
[image: a blue divided plate and a mug]
*A breakable version of a divided plate, durable plastic ones are often found and one time use ones as well.* Photo by [Kaszeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Kaszeta) Full [details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Diner_blue_plate.jpg).